# How to remove comma from a div

Tags: jquery, html, string

I have a div with anchor tag separated with commas. I am checking if the count of anchor is more than six, if yes, I am hiding all the anchor tags, but the commas with space are remaining.

How to remove commas along with the space?

Comment: If you find one of these answers useful, click on the checkbox next to the answer.  You can also go back and do this on your old questions by clicking your name at the top of the page.  Selecting an answer helps others solve their problems more quickly, and will also get others to give you better quality answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick you could do is not adding those separators (commas) directly into the markup, but using CSS `:after` pseudo-selector and `content` property. This way the commas become attached to the links.

HTML:

```
<a href="#">link 1</a>
<a href="#">link 2</a>
<a href="#">link 3</a>
<a href="#">link 4</a>
```

CSS:

```
a:after { content: ','; }
a:last-child:after { content: ''; }
```

Please check out my [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XAZVq/). Click the links to remove them.

**Alternatively**, you can also hide the surrounding div, so everything inside will become hidden (`$('#parentdiv').hide()`). I could give you a better and more detailed if you provided any details about your problem (current code, what do you expect to see, a jsFiddle would be best).